# TypeScript importing / DI a const value between Angular2 Classes / Components

Tags: typescript, angular, dependency-injection

Hi there in my Angular2 app I have a routes file called `routes.ts` like so (I have only included a few routes here)...

```
export const routes:DisplayRoutes = [
    {
        path: '',
        display: 'Home',
        component: HomeComponent
    }, {
        path: 'teams',
        display: 'Teams',
        component: LeftSubNavigation,
        index: {
            component: DetailMoreLayout
        },
        children: [
            {
                path: ':id',
                component: DetailMoreLayout
            }
        ]
    }, {
        path: 'contact',
        display: 'Contact',
        component: LeftSubNavigation,
        index: {
            component: DetailMoreLayout
        },
        children: [
            {
                path: ':id',
                component: DetailMoreLayout
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

`DisplayRoutes` is a custom type I made by extending the Route object, now I have another component folder with a component file in it, this is called `navigation.component.ts`. In this file I want to import the routes I declared in the `routes.ts` I've tried numerous ways (using `@Inject(routes)` but I just keep getting errors in the console...

```
import {
    routes
} from '../routes';

@Component({
               selector: 'navigation',
               templateUrl: './navigation.component.html',
               directives: [],
               pipes: []
           })
export class NavigationComponent {
    menuOpen:boolean = false;
    routes:any;

    constructor(private routes: routes, private router:Router) {

        this.routes = routes; // this won't work, how do I get hold of a copy of my routes... I need to loop through them, etc, etc...

        // more code below... etc...
    }
```

With the above I get the error `Can't resolve all parameters for NavigationComponent: (?, Router)'`

When I change the constructor to:

```
constructor(@Inject(routes) routes:DisplayRoutes, private router:Router)
```

I get the error: `browser_adapter.ts:82 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]!`

Any help would be appreciated. I am sure it is really easy, I just don't seem to be able to make this work!

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: I've had many, I'll update the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to inject into the constructor. The `import` statement is enough to have access to the `constant`:

```
import {routes} from '../routes';

@Component({
    selector: 'navigation',
    templateUrl: './navigation.component.html'
})
export class NavigationComponent {

    menuOpen: boolean = false;
    routes: any;

    constructor(private router:Router) {
        this.routes = routes; 
    }
}
```

If for some reason you do not want to assign it in the `constructor` which does seem a bit odd. You can also use a `getter` property:

```
import {routes} from '../routes';

@Component({
    selector: 'navigation',
    templateUrl: './navigation.component.html'
})
export class NavigationComponent {

    menuOpen: boolean = false;

    get routes(): any {
       return routes;
    }

    constructor(private router:Router) {}
}
```

Whatever floats your boat :)

Comment: Hi thanks! Of course! I stopped using that as I was able to write `routes`  to the console but not to the interface (or use it in a `ngFor`, for example `<div *ngFor="let route of routes">`) So, if I put a console.log(routes) in the constructor I see the object array, in the HTML I saw `<!--template bindings={"ng-reflect-ng-for-of": null}-->`in the rendered code. Maybe that is another question!

Comment: You can't use imported variables inside your template. You are right that you first have to assign them to a class property where the template belongs to. `this.routes = routes`

Comment: That's what I thought and now everything works, thanks for your help

Comment: @MarkSandman I've updated my answer with another possibility to address this problem. It's a bit cleaner solution